# When I click on the image I put a filter on it which effects the border of the image aswell, how can i make the border resistent to that?

Tags: html, css

Here is the code:

```css
.championlock:active {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.championlock:hover {
    border: 5px solid #93d3fe;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.championlock {
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.05s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.05s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.05s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.05s;
    transition-duration: 0.05s;
}
```

```html
<a href="trundlesupportguide.html" target="_blank"><img class="championlock" src="http://www.counter-lol.de/Trundle.png" alt="Trundle Icon" width="100%" style="max-width:62px;"></a>
```

I want the border to stay blue, how can I do that?

http://jsfiddle.net/ow4pgyzk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the border to the `a` tag (the parent).

```css
a {
  display:inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  border: 5px solid #93d3fe;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

a img {
  display:block;
}

.championlock:active {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.championlock{
  border: none; 
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.05s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.05s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.05s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.05s;
  transition-duration: 0.05s;
}
```

```html
<a href="trundlesupportguide.html" target="_blank">
  <img class="championlock" src="http://www.counter-lol.de/Trundle.png" alt="Trundle Icon" width="100%" style="max-width:62px;">
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to change the border to the a tag after i posted this post, but my border arround the a tag was too small for the img and had a lower z-index.

Comment: That's why you need to add the `a` tag `display:inline-block` and the `img` tag `display:block`